# how to extract the token and id from the route exercise using httpParams in Angular?

Tags: angular

route example:
https://example.com/painel.html?token=00Kjs9jmAuxruH6oXrng6shC11yngHv#!/exercise/3e13eb84-d2c71bc5f7a9

exercise id: 3e13eb84-d2c71bc5f7a9
token: 00Kjs9jmAuxruH6oXrng6shC11yngHv#!

Sorry for bad English

Answer (score 0):

This way you can access queryParams:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.queryParams.subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res) //will give query params as an object
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but the url I get through window.location.href, as it is an external route. In this way, as described, I can only get information regarding my internal route.